# VFP unknown property integer.optdesc

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, repeat

I included snippets of desired results, controller, and VFP below. I am trying to get to the optdesc and udcdesc values. When I try using !opt.optdesc it gives unknown property integer.optdesc.

| Product |  |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 333 |
| AGD | 4444 |

| Geometric |  |
| --- | --- |
| ASD | 333 |
| FWS | 333 |

Below is the snippet from my controller. I also included my VFP code.

{1=Tab:[options={1=Option:[optdesc=333, udcdesc=ABC], 2=Option:[optdesc=4444, udcdesc=AGD]}, tabname=Product], 2=Tab:[options={1=Option:[optdesc=333, udcdesc=ASD], 2=Option:[optdesc=333, udcdesc=FWS]}, tabname=Geometric]}

```
public class Tab{
        public String tabname {get; private set;}
        public Map<Decimal,Option> options {get; private set;}
    }
    
    public class Option{
        public String optdesc {get; private set;}
        public String udcdesc {get; private set;}
    }
    
    public Map<Decimal,Tab> getAllOptions {
        get{
            Map<Decimal,Tab> tabs = new Map<Decimal,Tab>();
            
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            tab.tabname='Product';
            
            Map<Decimal,Option> options = new Map<Decimal,Option>();
            
            Option option= new Option();
            option.udcdesc='ABC';
            option.optdesc='333';
            options.put(1,option);
            
            option= new Option();
            option.udcdesc='AGD';
            option.optdesc='4444';
            options.put(2,option);
            
            tab.options = options;
            tabs.put(1,tab);
            
            /* ********* */
            
            tab = new Tab();
            tab.tabname='Geometric';
            
            options = new Map<Decimal,Option>();
            
            option= new Option();
            option.udcdesc='ASD';
            option.optdesc='333';
            options.put(1,option);
            
            option= new Option();
            option.udcdesc='FWS';
            option.optdesc='333';
            options.put(2,option);
            
            tab.options=options;
            tabs.put(2,tab);
            
            /* ********* */
            
            return tabs; 
        }private set;
    }
```

VFP

```
<apex:page controller="Optionsv2Controller" standardStylesheets="false">
    <div>  
        <div>Optionsv2</div>
        <table>
            <apex:repeat value="{!getAllOptions}" var="tab">
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!getAllOptions[tab].tabname}"></apex:outputText></td>
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!getAllOptions[tab]}" var="opt">
                    <tr>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!getAllOptions[tab][opt].udcdesc}"></apex:outputText></td>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!getAllOptions[tab][opt].optdesc}"></apex:outputText></td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:repeat> 
        </table>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: In the linked post above, note the use of `{!map[fieldKey1][fieldKey2]}` for a nested map structure.

Comment: Hi  David, I received Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received Tab. I updated the VFP code above to what I attempted to use. I appreciate the link you provided. It helped me make sense of what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. VFP looked as follows for anyone with similar issue.

```
<apex:page controller="Optionsv2Controller" standardStylesheets="false">
    <div>  
        <div>Optionsv2</div>
        <table>
            <apex:repeat value="{!getAllOptions}" var="tab">
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!getAllOptions[tab].tabname}"></apex:outputText></td>
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!getAllOptions[tab].options}" var="opt">
                    <tr>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!getAllOptions[tab].options[opt].udcdesc}"></apex:outputText></td>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!getAllOptions[tab].options[opt].optdesc}"></apex:outputText></td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:repeat> 
        </table>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: you should add a sentence explaining why the above fixed the issue -- that said, we really appreciate the Q&A type answers where one solves their own issues